# Android : Set Call forwarding after a delay

Tags: android, call, delay, forward

I am trying to set call forwarding option in my App with a delay.
Like I get call, It displays for 5 or 10 sec,
So I see, if its from my family or friends I can pick the call,
Or
else after the delay, It should automatically be forwarded to the set mobile number.

I have written the below function to set forward.

Help me to add delay to it like 5 sec or 10 sec.

```
void fwdCalSetSecBtnFnc()
{
    if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
    {
        Intent calFwdIntentVar = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_CALL);
        String mobNumVar = FwdMobNumTxt.getText().toString();
        String fwdMobNumVar = ("**21*" + mobNumVar + "#");
        calFwdIntentVar.setData(Uri.fromParts("tel", fwdMobNumVar, "#"));
        calFwdIntentVar.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
        startActivity(calFwdIntentVar);
    }
}
```

Comment: For the delay use system Time... It will work...

Comment: Also you can use a `Handler`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> UUID Code Links : 
> http://www.theunwired.net/?item=how-to-diverting-voice-calls-by-using-ussd-codes>
>
> UUID Code 21 Diverts all Calls
>
> So to Divert if no Reply we have to Use
>   UUID Code 61

So Replace :

```
String fwdMobNumVar = ("**21*" + mobNumVar + "#");
```

with

=> For 5 Sec Delay :

```
String fwdMobNumVar = ("**61*" + mobNumVar + "*" + 5 + "#");
```

=> For 10 Sec Delay :

```
String fwdMobNumVar = ("**61*" + mobNumVar + "*" + 10 + "#");
```